# How to shutdown mongodb sharded cluster temporary

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have setup mongodb sharded cluster with following topology

- 3x3 shards (each have 2 replica sets)
- 1x3 config server replica cluster
- 2 mongos routers

I want to shutdown whole cluster temporary keeping data integrity intact.
I may use this setup later so I do not want to scrap whole setup.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. stop balancing - run `sh.stopBalancer()` from `mongos`
2. shutdown `mongos` services - run `db.shutdownServer()` from `mongos`
3. shutdown config mongod services - run `db.shutdownServer()` from config server `mongod`
4. shutdown shards mongod services - run `db.shutdownServer()` from replica set `mongod`